# Are there any security risks for moving the DomainRoot of Apache2 to /home/ubuntu/www?

Tags: apache2

I was wondering if it was safe to move the DomainRoot of apache2 to `/home/ubuntu/www`. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS. I haven't found many articles about this. It doesn't seem safe, but I don't know why. Can you please help?

This is my current conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName Subdomain.MySite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/www

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/www>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```